# Show names of positional arguments inlayed

Tags: python, pycharm

I've recently been doing some programming in Rust using Clion. This provides a utility whereby when you pass positional arguments to a function it will show you which argument will pick up each value (as if you had passed them in as keyword arguments) see below:

[image: edit with parameter names inlayed]

I've found this to be a very nice feature as it's made code a fair bit more readable and prevented me making a couple of stupid mistakes. Therefore, I'd love to have this functionality in PyCharm for programming Python, does anyone know of a plugin which can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [Python Inlay Params](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19538-python-inlay-params) plugin does what you want. It adds inlay hints both for callable parameters, values, and for types on variables.

Here's a convenient snippet transcribed from the demo for testing:

```py
class Dimens:
    width: int
    height: int

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


a = Dimens(1, 2)
```

And a screenshot in action using PyCharm 2022.1 Pro

[image: Inlay Params plugin in action]

See the Settings instructions on the [Python Inlay Params GitHub's page](https://github.com/WhiteMemory99/intellij-python-inlay-params#settings). The above snippet worked for me using the default settings after installing the plugin.

---

---

For pytest users there's also the [Pytest Parametrize Inlay Hint](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20053-pytest-parametrize-inlay-hint).
Just for type hints and not variables (thus not for parameters or values) there's also [Python Inlay Hints](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18174-python-inlay-hints).

There aren't currently any other plugins [for PyCharm on JetBrains marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=pycharm) that do what you want.

---

---

It should be mentioned that using PyCharm without plugins you can already get values for parameters shown in the editor just using the debugger. For example with the following snippet:

```py
def my_func(a: int, b: str):
    c = a
    c = c + 1
    print(str(a), b)
    return


my_func(1, 'b')
```

During debugging the values will be shown alongside the variables and the parameters, although not embedded in the code of the signatures themselves. As shown in the screenshot:

[image: editor during debugging]

To configure the shown functionality go to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Build, Execution, Deployment` `>` `Debugger` `>` `Data Views` and under `Editor` check `Show values inline`. See the PyCharm documentation [View values inline](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/examining-suspended-program.html#inline-view).

[image: IDE settings Show values inline]

Comment: Python inlay params looks perfect. However, I have added it to my environment and it doesn't appear to be working. Is there any particular setup which needs to be performed?

Comment: I am aware of the ability to use the debugger. However, I often have to work with numpy and matplotlib which can have confusing positioning of arguments and where the cost of rerunning or running in debug mode is high. Thus my desire for something which will show arguments while coding.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 I edited the question, the plugin worked for me right after installation without having to restart the IDE and just using the default pre-configured settings (If it doesn't work: try restarting the IDE, invalidating caches, creating a new project, check manually that the settings are properly configured, and verify what IDE version you're on). See the [supported versions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19538-python-inlay-params/versions#tabs) it should work on PyCharm up to the latest version. If it still doesn't work you should post your system spec on the GitHub issue page.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 I just tested it again and restarting the IDE might be necessary to get it to work.

Comment: could I please check what version you're using. I'm currently on 0.1.4, apparently anything more recent requires pycharm 213 or above, (I am currently on 212 and it appears that 213 is not currently stable)

Comment: @Pioneer_11 I'm using PyCharm 2022.1 the plugin installes with 0.3.1 and starts working immediately (not requiring IDE restart). If you're on PyCharm 2021.2 yes you'll get the plugin version 0.1.4. Notice that your IDE version PyCharm 2021.2 is the lowest supported version and only 1 plugin release supports it. Your best chance is just updating the IDE to any later version in which case you'll get latest plugin version.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 [your PyCharm is 4 versions behind](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/other.html) and almost 1 year old. You should update because those intermediate versions are all stable by now (barring one or the other version specific bug). If you update to PyCharm 2022.1 I can guarantee I haven't found any bugs or instability with it.

Comment: are you able to get it working with functions? I have updated my version of my pycharm and it now works perfectly with classes but I still cannot get it to work with functions.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 Yes it's working for me with functions, [here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPPl4.png). If it's not working for functions verify the [plugin's settings as shown on GitHub](https://github.com/WhiteMemory99/Intellij-Python-Inlay-Params#settings) (I had already linked to the settings in the post.) The previous screenshot in this comment shows it working with default settings and where the settings are.